# electron app is getting 34352:0406/075851.692:ERROR:CONSOLE(6)] "console.assert"

Tags: javascript, electron

In my electron app I'd like to use `console.trace()` but want it to be collapsed by default. For that I use this in renderer process:

```
{
  const {groupCollapsed, groupEnd, trace} = console;

  console.trace = ((...args:any[]) =>
  {
    groupCollapsed(...args);
    trace("");
    groupEnd();
  }).bind(console);
}
```

It works ok (time to time few messages from async functions getting grouped together), however in main process I'm bombarded by these messages (each `trace` call generates several lines):

```
[34352:0406/075851.692:ERROR:CONSOLE(6)] "console.assert", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/panels/console/console.js (6)
```

I'm unable reproduce this exact message with an [electron snippet](https://gist.github.com/36370e420a7d8702706280603778a57a) using electron v18.0.2, but it shows similar message instead:

```
[5636:0406/083113.750:INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "test", source: file:///C:/Users/dev/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp-34776-vztptWEofKLe/renderer.js (5)
[5636:0406/083113.751:INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "console.groupEnd", source: file:///C:/Users/dev/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp-34776-vztptWEofKLe/renderer.js (7)
```

so how can I see where that error is coming from (aka `devtools://devtools/bundled/panels/console/console.js`) and most importantly how to suppress it?

[EDIT]

This seems to have nothing to do with me replacing `console.trace`. It seems the issue is in electron itself. The last version that didn't have this issue was `18.0.0-alpha.5,` since `18.0.0-beta.1` these messages appear. If I clear developer tools console, the messages stop for a while, but after some time they start showing up again with each message in dev tools.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: No, it seems to be a bug, since it happens without altering console functions.

Comment: Already reported in Electron issues: [\[Bug\]: Console.assert errors](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/35399)